# stratum connection interrupted problem

Tags: monerod, windows, error-log

stratum connection interrupted problem always present and no yay or accepted. Im using GTX 780 and my hash rate is insanely high.You can refer to the pic below, hope someone can help me solve this problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The incredible high/impossible hashrate suggest something went wrong indeed.

If you have overclocked your graphics card, then revert to the original factory settings and try again.

Also you should try again with a lower amount of blocks/threads and slowly increase it.

Finally you should also update your drivers to the latest version, if your not already on latest one.